# Ruby get methods defined in codebase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get a list of the methods defined in our Rails codebase, without including anything defined in superclass or dynamically defined at runtime. I've tried `instance_methods(false)`, but a ton of methods are returned:

```
> User.instance_methods(false).length
=> 310
```

I'm guessing this is because Rails defines a bunch of methods at runtime. Is there any way to get a list of the methods only defined in the files in our app? Hoping there's a Ruby way and not just running a grep across all of the files. Bonus points for class methods as well...

Comment: If it inherits from ActiveRecord::Base, you might try `User.methods.sort - ActiveRecord::Base.methods`

Comment: The problem is that ActiveRecord generates a lot of methods in its subclasses based on the database attributes: `(User.instance_methods(false) - ActiveRecord::Base.instance_methods(false)).size # => 310`

Answer (score 1):

`User.instance_methods` will show all the inherited methods as well, so you should run something like that

```
User.instance_methods - User.superclass.instance_methods
```

Be ware thought that it will show heaps of other methods that are generated by AR when you inherited the `ActiveRecord::Base` class

Comment: `.instance_methods(false)` excludes superclass methods: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods

Answer (score 0):

Use `MyClass.instance_methods(false)`, but make sure to pass `false` as an argument if you don't want it to return the methods defined in the superclasses.

Additionally, use `MyClass.singleton_methods(false)` for class methods.

More info:

- https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/singleton_methods
- https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/instance_methods